# Can't get javascript working (beginner) - please check my code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm new to scripting etc, so I'd appreciate if you could tell me (a) why my code isn't working and (b) any other useful tips you can offer. I'm sure the reason is very simple :). Happy for any feedback.

I'm just designing a basic calculator - the user inputs an animal's weight, dehydration level and another figure, and the javascript makes a few calculations to output a fluid rate (for calculating how fast fluid should run into a sick animal).

The code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

document.write("this script is working");

// Veterinary Calculator Code



//  update maint, replacement, dailyRequirement and rate when bw, dh or ol changes.
function updateDetails() {
 
 // define variables for body weight, dehydration and ongoing losses
 var $bw = $('#bodyWeight');
 var $dh = $('#dehydration');
 var $ol = $('#ongoingLosses');
 var $dr = $('#dailyRequirement');
 var $repl = $('#replacement');

 var $rt = $('#rate');

 var mt = (1.5 * (70 * (math.pow($bw.val, 0.75)))); // maintenance requirement
 $dr.text(mt + 'ml/24 hours');
 
 var rep = $bw * 0.01 * $dh;
 $repl.text(rep + 'ml');
 
 var rt = ((mt + rep + $ol.val)/24);
 $rt.text(rt + "ml/hr");
 }



// add event listeners for input elements
$bw.on('change', updateDetails());
$dh.on('change', updateDetails());
$ol.on('change', updateDetails());

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <!-- Always force latest IE rendering engine (even in intranet) & Chrome Frame
  Remove this if you use the .htaccess -->
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">

  <title>Veterinary Calculators</title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="Cameron Fay">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0">

  <!-- Replace favicon.ico & apple-touch-icon.png in the root of your domain and delete these references -->
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/apple-touch-icon.png">
 </head>

 <body>
  <div>
   <header>
    <h1>Fluid Calculator</h1>
   </header>
   

   <div>
    <fieldset id="params">
     <legend>Inputs</legend>
     <label>Body Weight (kg):</label><br />
     <input type="number" id="bodyWeight" autofocus min="0" />
     <br><br />
     <label>% Dehydration:</label><br />
     <input type="number" id="dehydration"/>
     <br /><br />
     <label> Losses (ml):</label><br />
     <input type="number" id="ongoingLosses" />
     <br /><br />  
          
    </fieldset><br />

    <label>Daily Requirement:</label> <label class="result" id="dailyRequirement"></label> <br />
    <label>Replacement:</label> <label class="result" id="replacement"></label> <br />
    
    
    <br />
    <label> Rate (ml/hr):</label> <label class="result" id="rate"></label>
   </div>

   <footer>
    <p>  
     &copy; Copyright 2015 by VETsharp Pty Ltd
    </p>
   </footer>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="vc.js"></script>
  
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `$bw` , `$dh` and `$ol` are on local scope. You can't find them out of the function scope. And you also need to declare those before you use them.

Comment: You also need ); at the end of your Javascript.

Comment: Also it's `$bw.val()` not `$bw.val`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Problems :***

1. You declared the `var`'s inside the function but bind the `change` event where the `var`'s are unknown (out of the function scope). So you must declare those on a parent scope which is in your case outside the function.
2. It's `.val()` which is a method not `.val` in jQuery.
3. You need to pass a function pointer when a event is fired inside `.on()` method. It's called an event handler. It's not same as calling a function. So it's

`$bw.on('change', updateDetails);` not `$bw.on('change', updateDetails());`

***Solution :*** 
This is what your script should look like,

```
$bw = $('#bodyWeight');
$dh = $('#dehydration');
$ol = $('#ongoingLosses');

//update maint, replacement, dailyRequirement and rate when bw, dh or ol changes.
function updateDetails()    {
// define variables for body weight, dehydration and ongoing losses
   var $dr = $('#dailyRequirement');
    var $repl = $('#replacement');

    var $rt = $('#rate');

    var mt = (1.5 * (70 * (Math.pow($bw.val(), 0.75))));    // maintenance requirement
    $dr.text(mt + 'ml/24 hours');

    var rep = $bw.val() * 0.01 * $dh.val();
    $repl.text(rep + 'ml');

    var rt = ((mt + rep + $ol.val())/24);
    $rt.text(rt + "ml/hr");
}



// add event listeners for input elements
$bw.on('change', updateDetails);
$dh.on('change', updateDetails);
$ol.on('change', updateDetails);
```

[***jsFiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/codeSpy/qzc183xj/)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. Can I ask, you've left out the document.ready part - do I even need this as I have placed the script at the end of the html file?

Comment: yes you of course need this in your HTML file. But in `jsFiddle` they internally put all your code in `document.ready(function(){ });`. So there you don't need it. That means in `jsFiddle` all your code start working after the document is ready.

Comment: Strange...when I follow your link to jsFiddle, the code works there (albeit I need to polish it a lot), however when I copy and paste the code into my files (which are just stored locally on my computer), they don't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You should provide function references for event handlers. Fix your code like this:

```
$bw.on('change', updateDetails);
$dh.on('change', updateDetails);
$ol.on('change', updateDetails);
```

The difference is that `updateDetails()` executes the function immediately and returns `undefined` as event handler, so basically no handler is registered at all.

Another problem is that you need to move variable definitions outside `updateDetails` function:

```
var $bw = $('#bodyWeight');
var $dh = $('#dehydration');
var $ol = $('#ongoingLosses');
var $dr = $('#dailyRequirement');
var $repl = $('#replacement');

function updateDetails() { ... }
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for this.
Can you just explain why? I only intend on using those variables within that function - isn't it better practice to keep variables local?

Comment: *"I only intend on using those variables within that function"* But you also want to bind event handlers out side of the function. So in this case you anyway need them outside. In general in this case it's better to declare them outside so they are not recalculated on each event when function is executed.

Answer (score 0):

Where to start...

- You are missing the closing `)` and `;` after your document.ready.
- You are trying to declare a new function inside a function.
- You are trying to use [$.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) with an old version of jquery.

There are probably more that i cannot see at a glance. Your spaces and indents are horrible overall.

Comment: Hi, can you please explain the 'old version of jQuery' comment - I'm using 1.11.2 straight from the jquery site?